# Why can't I dynamic_cast "sideways" during multiple inheritence?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, dynamic-cast, object-lifetime

The following code throws std::bad_cast

```
struct Foo {
    void foo () {}
};

struct Bar {
    Bar () {
        dynamic_cast <Foo &> (*this) .foo ();
    }
    virtual ~ Bar () {}
};

struct Baz : public Foo, public Bar {
};

int main ()
{
    Baz b;
}
```

I remember once reading how dynamic_cast has implementation performance trade-offs because "it traverses the full inheritence lattice" in order to evaluate correctly. What the compiler needs to do here is first cast up and then down again.

Is it possible to make the above work or do I need to add
`virtual Foo* Bar::as_foo()=0;`
?

Comment: Not `lattice`. Up/Down the inheritance tree.

Comment: @Martin, in this example it's a tree, but C++ inheritance is more generally a directed graph and not a tree.  @spraff: I think you're wanting a *down* cast first, to `Baz`, and then an *up* cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no virtual functions in Foo, so dynamic_cast is perfectly obliged to fail. There needs to be a virtual function. It's also a bad idea to do so during construction, as you're going to run into construction order issues.

Comment: "_There are no virtual functions in Foo_" How is that relevant?

Comment: @curiousguy You can only use `dynamic_cast` on a polymorphic object (or, as you experience, you get a `bad_cast` exception). An object is only polymorphic if its type has at least one virtual function.

Comment: @rubenvb "_as you experience, you get a bad_cast exception_" no, you get nothing!

Comment: @curiousguy Right. My bad. `bad_cast`s are thrown when casting to reference types and you would have gotten a `nullptr` if you were casting to pointer types (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84ef0c302f8097d5).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Bar` should inherit from `Foo` (which it does not in the current example), the problem you're seeing here is commonly refered to as the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).  Which version of `foo` do you want to use, the `Bar::foo()` or the `Foo::foo()`?  You're going to need to specify a virtual inheritance:

```
struct Foo{
    ~virtual Foo(){}
     void foo(){}
};

struct Bar : virtual public Foo

struct Baz : virtual public Foo, public Bar
```

to let it know that there should only exist one type of `foo()`.  Hence, [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) is used to invoke the call to `foo()` within the constructor.

Edit:

And to be clear, I am assuming you want `Bar` to inherit from `Foo`.  If you don't have that in your code then that's the cause of the bad cast error.  There's no inheritance hierarchy for `Bar` to traverse to get to `Foo`.  Also, modern compilers shouldn't even compile without the virtual inheritance but certain legacy compilers will happily @#$#$ it up.

And if I'm going to comment on another answer, I better follow through with my own answer!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but Bar doesn't inherit from Foo at all. Unless you're assuming that's a typo

Comment: @Falmarri I am, you're seeing the first version which I quickly edited.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the diamond problem.

Comment: "`struct Baz : virtual public Foo, public Bar`" why do you need to write `virtual public Foo` here?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong in your example, perhaps it's an accident?

Bar does not inherit from Foo, so it cannot be cast down to Foo in the constructor of Bar. They also do not share a common inheritance parent, and therefore cannot be cast between each other (sideways). What you probably want is:

```
struct withFoo {
    virtual void foo () {}
    virtual ~withFoo() {}
};

struct Foo : public virtual withFoo {
};

struct Bar : public virtual withFoo {
    Bar () {
        foo();  // no need to cast!
    }
};

struct Baz : public Foo, public Bar {
};

int main ()
{
    Baz b;
    b.foo(); // because of virtual inheritance from withFoo, there is no ambiguity here 
}
```

Hope this helps! If you need clarifications, please ask!

Comment: You've forgotten the virtual destructor in `withFoo`.

Comment: @wheaties Thanks! I have indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a Baz involves constructing its bases, and one of those is a Bar. The Bar base of the Baz is not castable to Foo, even if the final Baz should be.